# How to add a jar to the classpath of a project using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm using Eclipse as IDE, and I would like to add a jar to the `classpath` of a Java project.

However, I can find only a way to add the jar to the project `buildpath`.

How can I add a jar to a project `classpath` using Eclipse?

Comment: If you run it from Eclipse, it should already include the whole build path in the run configurations. If you want to run it outside of Eclipse, you have to do it yourself (or build a standalone executable jar that bundles all its dependencies).

Comment: Hi Thilo, yes I'm running it from Eclipse. I'll try to explain better why I think the jar is not included in the classpath.
I have a Java Project with a custom annotation and its annotation processor. I exported this project as jar project with the javax.annotation.processing.Processor file inside META-INF/services.
Now I have another project that is using my custom annotation. In this second project, I included the jar of the first project (A) and another jar (B).
The annotation processor needs a Class object referencing an interface declared in jar (B), and it's using Class.forName [...]

Comment: [...] to do this; however, the method throws a ClassNotFoundException, because the jar (C) is not included in the classpath of the project; so my question is: how can I include the jar (C) in the classpath of the project? thank you :)

Comment: The missing class is from jar(B) or from jar(C)? Did you include both in the build path for the second project?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in the first post. 
The missing class is from jar(C), and I included both jar in the build path of the second project.
The annotation processor is running, I see the exception thrown during execution.

Comment: Does it work outside of Eclipse with a manually set classpath? Maybe the classpath is not the real problem?

Comment: I run the following command from the command line

javac -cp \path\to\folder\lib\* \path\to\folder\src\*.java

and I obtained no error.

In Eclipse instead I'm still getting the ClassNotFoundException

Comment: You should be able to add extra classpath entries in the Run Configurations. As to why it is is necessary here, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user library in Eclipse.

Eclipse version for steps: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

1. Steps for adding an User Library:
   Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> New -> input library name like "testUserLib" -> Add JARs / Add External JARs -> OK
2. Steps for applying an User Library to Java Project:
   Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> User Library -> choose "testUserLib" -> Finish -> OK

[www.hkbn.net](https://www.hkbn.net)
A purpose-driven company: Make our Hong Kong a Better Place to Live